# I'm getting a "error: no matching function for call to 'leftRotate' when compiling

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
using namespace std;

void leftRotate(int arr[]){

    unsigned int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout<<"Value: " << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}


//function declaration

void leftRotate(int arr[]);

int main(){

    std::list<int> l = {1,2,3,4,5};

    leftRotate(l);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `std::list` isn't an array.

Comment: reading the complete error message would help

Comment: not the error, but you dont need to place a declaration after the definition

Comment: Make sure you [turn on your compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vmgnfB). You have a grave runtime error inside the function waiting to bite you.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` - ehh, we have [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size). But, why a C-style array in the first place? Why not `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

`std::list<int>` is not equivalent to array `int arr[]`,hence, you don't have `leftRotate` function that accepts `std::list<int>` the compiler throws this error.

In order to solve this , depending on what your project needs, you either have to change:

- the declaration of l to int `int l[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4,5};`
- Or the leftRotate definition and declaration to `void leftRotate(std::list<int> arr)`.

Note: As mentioned in the comments. Unlike many other languages, In C and C++ you need to be explicit on how to pass parameters to functions, either by copying the data structure and everything in it to a new instance (passing by value) or by passing a pointer or reference to the original instance (passing by reference).
In your case the later option is more sensible, however the code you have and what being suggested is implementing the first option.
For more introductory information https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parameter-passing-techniques-in-c-cpp/

Comment: "_to void leftRotate(std::list arr)._" `std::list` isn't a valid type tho, like `std::list<int>` would be.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, updated the answer, thanks for the note

Comment: Why take the list by value?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica, no technical reason. the question is not about value , reference parameters, and I don't want to change the code snippets unnecessarily

Comment: You should at least mention it if you're going to suggest passing a container into a function, with a code example no less

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is connected with the declaration of your `void leftRotate`, as its input is an array of integers, while you declare `l` as the `std::list<int>`. You would have to change one of these (function or data) in order to make your program work, which means you must use **only one type** at a time. The possibilities are:

```
void leftRotate(int arr[]) {...}

int main()
{
    int l[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    leftRotate(l);
}
```

or

```
void leftRotate(std::list<int> &s) {...}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> l = {1,2,3,4,5};
    leftRotate(l);
}
```